# Hadoop Yarn Default queue ‘s Resources are all 0(both vCores and Memory) all the time so application submitted can't turn from ACCEPTED to RUNNING

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have three servers, each with 2GB RAM and 2 CPU cores. I had previously configured a Hadoop cluster (version 2.8.0) and could run MapReduce jobs using Java. Now, I'm in the process of setting up Spark (version 2.0.1-bin.without-hadoop) with a Scala environment. After writing a WordCount.scala program in Scala, I would like to submit a job for testing using the command.

`spark-submit WordCount.jar /folder/file-1.txt`

Once the submission is complete, I intend to access the Hadoop web UI, where I found that the application to be in the "ACCEPTED" state all the time. And I get Diagnostics.

`[Sun Nov 05 14:03:50 +0800 2023] Application is added to the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as cluster resource is empty. Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:1024, vCores:1>; Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:0, vCores:0>; User AM Resource Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>; Queue AM Resource Usage = <memory:0, vCores:0>;`

I checked queue status page only to find that

- Max Application Master Resources: <memory:0, vCores:0>
- Used Application Master Resources:    <memory:0, vCores:0>
- Max Application Master Resources Per User:    <memory:0, vCores:0>

[screenshot of the queue status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAK3c.png)

I tried to change capacity-scheduler.xml and restart Hadoop but it didn't change anything. Please help me fix this problem.

Here is my capacity-scheduler.xml file:

```xml
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
      Maximum number of applications that can be pending and running.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>0.5</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run 
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
    <description>
      The ResourceCalculator implementation to be used to compare 
      Resources in the scheduler.
      The default i.e. DefaultResourceCalculator only uses Memory while
      DominantResourceCalculator uses dominant-resource to compare 
      multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
    <value>default</value>
    <description>
      The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Default queue user limit a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
    <description>
      The maximum capacity of the default queue. 
    </description>
  </property>

  <!-- Ensure the default queue has minimum capacity -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.minimum-capacity</name>
    <value>1</value> <!-- This ensures that the default queue has some minimum capacity -->
    <description>
      The minimum capacity of the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can submit jobs to the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can administer jobs on the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay</name>
    <value>40</value>
    <description>
      Number of missed scheduling opportunities after which the CapacityScheduler 
      attempts to schedule rack-local containers. 
      Typically this should be set to number of nodes in the cluster, By default is setting 
      approximately number of nodes in one rack which is 40.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>
      A list of mappings that will be used to assign jobs to queues
      The syntax for this list is [u|g]:[name]:[queue_name][,next mapping]*
      Typically this list will be used to map users to queues,
      for example, u:%user:%user maps all users to queues with the same name
      as the user.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      If a queue mapping is present, will it override the value specified
      by the user? This can be used by administrators to place jobs in queues
      that are different than the one specified by the user.
      The default is false.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.per-node-heartbeat.maximum-offswitch-assignments</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Controls the number of OFF_SWITCH assignments allowed
      during a node's heartbeat. Increasing this value can improve
      scheduling rate for OFF_SWITCH containers. Lower values reduce
      "clumping" of applications on particular nodes. The default is 1.
      Legal values are 1-MAX_INT. This config is refreshable.
    </description>
  </property>


  <property>
          <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
          <value>1536</value>
  </property>
    <property>
          <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
          <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
          <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
          <value>1536</value>
  </property>
  <property>
          <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
          <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores </name>
          <value>6</value>
  </property>
  <property>
          <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb </name>
          <value>1536</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You should consider upgrading to Hadoop and Spark 3, not running such old versions. In any case, you've not shown enough information, since it's not a config error. Is YARN Nodemanager process actually running? How many active nodes are shown by the ResourceManager?

Comment: Related blog since you have such low resources on your cluster (modern computers can have 8 cores and 8GB RAM, or more). https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html